# Oracle 12c : Failed to install sample schema on Windows 10

Tags: database, oracle, windows-10

I've gone through lots of trial and errors and still can't get it right.
I have a pluggable database named **PDB01**.
I have an instantclient installed for the use of PL/SQL developer, but not sure if this affects the installation.

Things I've done: Major Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00003

1. Install Oracle Database Example
2. Set TWO_TASK variable as indicated in this discussion: 
   https://community.oracle.com/message/11234394#11234394
   http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TWO_TASK

   ```
   set two_task=pdb01
   ```
3. Edit tnsnames.ora to include the PDB name as discussed here:
   https://community.oracle.com/message/13570347#13570347

   ```
   PDB01 =
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vm21)(PORT = 1521))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = pdb01)
       )
     )
   ```
4. Connect to sys:

   ```
   connect sys/password@pdb01 as sysdba
   ```
5. Run the `hr_main.sql` script:

   ```
   @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql
   specify password for HR as parameter 1:
   Enter value for 1: xxxx
   specify default tablespace for HR as parameter 2:
   Enter value for 2: users
   specify temporary tablespace for HR as parameter 3:
   Enter value for 3: temp
   specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
   Enter value for 4: xxxx (same as the password of SYS)
   specify log path as parameter 5:
   Enter value for 5: D:\app\OracleHomeUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\demo\schema\log
   ```

   And then I got :

   ```
   Connected.
   GRANT execute ON sys.dbms_stats TO hr
                                      *
   ERROR at line 1:
   ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist

   ERROR:
   ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

   Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating REGIONS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating COUNTRIES table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating LOCATIONS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating DEPARTMENTS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating JOBS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating EMPLOYEES table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating JOB_HISTORY table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Creating EMP_DETAILS_VIEW view ...
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating REGIONS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating COUNTIRES table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating LOCATIONS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating DEPARTMENTS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating JOBS table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating EMPLOYEES table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   ******  Populating JOB_HISTORY table ....
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0640: Not connected
   SP2-0641: "EXECUTE" requires connection to server
   ```

hr_main.sql

```
    rem
    rem Header: hr_main.sql 09-jan-01
    rem
    rem Copyright (c) 2001, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. 
    rem All rights reserved. 
    rem
    rem Owner  : ahunold
    rem
    rem NAME
    rem   hr_main.sql - Main script for HR schema
    rem
    rem DESCRIPTON
    rem   HR (Human Resources) is the smallest and most simple one 
    rem   of the Sample Schemas
    rem   
    rem NOTES
    rem   Run as SYS or SYSTEM
    rem
    rem MODIFIED   (MM/DD/YY)
    rem   jmadduku  02/18/11 - Grant Unlimited Tablespace priv with RESOURCE
    rem   celsbern  06/17/10 - fixing bug 9733839
    rem   pthornto  07/16/04 - obsolete 'connect' role 
    rem   hyeh      08/29/02 - hyeh_mv_comschema_to_rdbms
    rem   ahunold   08/28/01 - roles
    rem   ahunold   07/13/01 - NLS Territory
    rem   ahunold   04/13/01 - parameter 5, notes, spool
    rem   ahunold   03/29/01 - spool
    rem   ahunold   03/12/01 - prompts
    rem   ahunold   03/07/01 - hr_analz.sql
    rem   ahunold   03/03/01 - HR simplification, REGIONS table
    rem   ngreenbe  06/01/00 - created

    SET ECHO OFF
    SET VERIFY OFF

    PROMPT 
    PROMPT specify password for HR as parameter 1:
    DEFINE pass     = &1
    PROMPT 
    PROMPT specify default tablespeace for HR as parameter 2:
    DEFINE tbs      = &2
    PROMPT 
    PROMPT specify temporary tablespace for HR as parameter 3:
    DEFINE ttbs     = &3
    PROMPT 
    PROMPT specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
    DEFINE pass_sys = &4
    PROMPT 
    PROMPT specify log path as parameter 5:
    DEFINE log_path = &5
    PROMPT

    -- The first dot in the spool command below is 
    -- the SQL*Plus concatenation character

    DEFINE spool_file = &log_path.hr_main.log
    SPOOL &spool_file

    REM =======================================================
    REM cleanup section
    REM =======================================================

    DROP USER hr CASCADE;

    REM =======================================================
    REM create user
    REM three separate commands, so the create user command 
    REM will succeed regardless of the existence of the 
    REM DEMO and TEMP tablespaces 
    REM =======================================================

    CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED BY &pass;

    ALTER USER hr DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs
          QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs;

    ALTER USER hr TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs;

    GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE VIEW, ALTER SESSION, CREATE SEQUENCE TO hr;
    GRANT CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE DATABASE LINK, RESOURCE , UNLIMITED         TABLESPACE TO hr;

    REM =======================================================
    REM grants from sys schema
    REM =======================================================

    CONNECT sys/&pass_sys AS SYSDBA;
    GRANT execute ON sys.dbms_stats TO hr;

    REM =======================================================
    REM create hr schema objects
    REM =======================================================

    CONNECT hr/&pass
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=American;
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=America;

    --
    -- create tables, sequences and constraint
    --

    @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_cre

    -- 
    -- populate tables
    --

    @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_popul

    --
    -- create indexes
    --

    @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_idx

    --
    -- create procedural objects
    --

    @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_code

    --
    -- add comments to tables and columns
    --

    @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_comnt

    --
    -- gather schema statistics
    --

    @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_analz

    spool off
```

Comment: Does user `HR` exist?

Comment: It didn't exist before I did any of the installation. But after several trials it was indeed created but has no tables or any other data stored inside. However, running hr_main.sql removes any previously installed HR schema as mentioned here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00005  so does it matter?

Comment: Normally, when creating a schema you can specify `INDENTIFIED BY password123`. When the schema (I'll call it `MYSCHEMA`) is created, a user `MYSCHEMA` is created and the password is set to `password123`. You could also create a user ahead of time, but you would need to then grant that user permissions to the new schema as soon as you create it before that user can modify or access the new schema. Could you provide the contents of `hr_main.sql` so we can see what, exactly, it is doing when you execute it?

Comment: I know how to create a local user (or schema). This is the official sample schema that Oracle provides for demonstration purpose. It is supposed to be installed along with the installation of the database, but somehow I didn't select the option to install the schema, and I don't want to uninstall and reinstall the database, so have to install it manually. I have put the hr_main.sql in the description.

Comment: I see the results of your run of hr_main.sql, can you provide the contents of that file, the actual sql script content of that file? Not the results of it being executed.

Comment: It should be in the description now, sorry for the delay...

Comment: Are you running this script logged in as a user that has access to perform all of these things? Able to create schemas, users, etc...

Comment: Yes I logged in to sys as sysdba

Comment: The manual http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001 has a note:  Make sure that you end the log directory name with a trailing slash, for example, $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/.   You didn't end the name with a trailing slash

Comment: I notice that too, but it should not be the cause of the problem. The trailing slash marks 'log' as the directory where the log will be put, and if no trailing slash the log will be put in the schema directory and the log file will be named "loghr_main.log" as in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by setting the LOCAL variable instead of TWO_TASK as the former is for Windows and the latter is for UNIX. Thanks to Balazs Papp in [answer of the same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139857/oracle-12c-unable-to-install-sample-schemata-on-windows-10/139860#139860)

So step 2 should be

```
set LOCAL=PDB01
```